# Disable notification abilities for libraries

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is it possible for me to stop an additional jar library from ever sending out any notifications?

I am an independent game developer and got recently contacted by a publisher that wants to work with me. The terms were alright and now I have to implement their advertising-sdk into the game and I am worried that they might use notification ads, that are against the developer policy (http://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html Ad Policy 3 "... Ads must not simulate or impersonate system notifications or warnings."). I do not want to risk getting my publisher account blocked.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no direct way of intercepting the showing of a `Notification` in your app.

But from my experience, if you will have to integrate an `advertising-sdk`, for them in order to display / receive notifications, they usually register `<receivers>` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, or require all kinds of `<permissions>`. For this to work, you need to add those actual `<receivers>` and `<permissions>` in your app, so if you will not declare those, the possible `Receivers` that would fire the `Notifications` won't work.

If you know that they launch or fire some `Notifications` let's say at app start... you can use [`NotificationManager.cancelAll()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) to cancel them.

Another thing that I would do maybe, would be to get access to their source code, and check if they do something "evil" there. If they do... try to break it or something.

Comment: The sdk does not require any special permissions, I simply init it via a method on Startup of my app. The way I have seen these Notifications happen is a long time after the app was closed, so calling cancelAll at startup won't help. Sourcecode would be great, but I was only provided a JAR-File.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't trust the provider of this JAR, don't put his code on your users' devices. Showing notifications is only one of many nefarious things he could do. Maybe you trap his notifications, but you don't realise he's secretly collecting the user's sensitive information to transmit over the internet. Maybe he shows pornographic adverts to users when your app is for children. Maybe he uses the user's device as part of a botnet or runs the user's battery down by mining bitcoins. There's no way you can detect any of these things.

You have to get the library author to describe the behaviour of his library, and commit in writing to what it does or doesn't do. If he won't do this, or you don't trust him to honour this agreement, bear in mind that you're responsible for any malware your app contains. In particular, I'd be inclined not to trust an ad network who emailed the address listed in Google Play: many of them are not at all trustworthy, and Airpush is by far the worst spammer in this respect.

Comment: Thanks for your input about what a developer should do. In this case I refused to publish it with their sdk under my account, but instead we're using the promoters account, causing them to risk one of their own publisher accounts. But I am still wondering if it is technically possible to hinder a third-party library from sending out notifications. Sadly it does not look good so far.

Answer (score 0):

These libraries need a background service to show the push ads in your app. Usually you'd need to add something like this to your manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.adnetworksdk.AdService" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.adnetworksdk.AdServicecom.yourapp.packagename" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
```

If this isn't in your manifest, nothing can run when your app isn't running so push ads can't be sent.

And if you really want to check, decompile the JAR using [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) and look through the source. It's probably obfuscated but you should be able to see what it's doing. Decompiling JARs to readable Java is surprisingly easy.

Comment: A service is not always needed since apps are usually not completely shut down when they are closed so this will not work. I myself use notifications in a game that lets the user know when some time-dependant action is finalised without using a service. Thanks for the input anyhow.